# Some email addresses appear to contain a newline?

Tags: git

I try to get the email address corresponding to specific commits, and I obtain:

```
$git show -s --pretty=tformat:"developer: %ce" b93ff31
developer: someuser@server.com

$git show -s --pretty=tformat:"developer: %ce" 4201b2b
developer: other@site.net
$
```

So, the first commit produces two newlines, the second only one (from `tformat`). As far as I can see, it is only commits from the first developer (a bot, actually), that contain this newline, but I don't know where it comes from. The .gitconfig file looks fine:

```
[user]
        name = Bot
        email = someuser@server.com
[color]
```

with no trailing blank, and saved with unix newlines, same as for other user whose email produces no newline. If I try to replace the email with `.mailmap`, I get the new email, but still the extra newline. What could be the reason for this and how to avoid it? Maybe different git versions (the commits with extra newline are generated with 1.8.3.1, those with 1.9.1 don't have the newline).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug:

> "git show -s" (i.e. show log message only) used to incorrectly emit
>      an extra blank line after a merge commit.
>      (merge ad2f725 mk/show-s-no-extra-blank-line-for-merges later to maint).

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.1.0.txt

Did `b93ff31` happen to be a merge commit?

I have Git version 2.11.0 and there's an extra newline after the developer line in this version also... so maybe a "feature" that keeps getting re-introduced?

Comment: Could indeed be, although I have 2.10.1 running on my main machine for this sort of thing, and `git show -s` doesn't accidentally add newlines to merge commits there.

Comment: Ah... yes indeed, the commits created by the bot are merge commits. So the newline is only being introduced by `git show -s`. For my purposes, replacing it with `git log -1` cures it.

Answer (score 2):

The email address inside a commit literally *cannot* contain a newline, as the commit internal format is a series of newline-separated lines, with the first empty line (adjacent pair of newlines) delimiting the Git-reserved header area from the subject and body (user defined) area.  It could, however, contain a character that causes your display to move down.

You could look at the raw contents of the commit object `b93ff31`,

```
$ git cat-file -p b93ff31 | vis -lt
```

for instance, assuming you have `vis`; or use some other viewer that you know will show you "weird stuff".  For instance, here is what is in a commit in the Git repository for Git:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD | vis -lt
tree 52060094c97b5ecff0a60e738c858dc8079fc01a\$
parent 3c4ce8e69b4838efce72d090b85bbbbb6eacc5bc\$
parent b32fe956d0d8d601e2dc915d96e14d8bbdda6b71\$
author Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1485898499 -0800\$
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1485898499 -0800\$
\$
Sync with maint\$
\$
* maint:\$
  Ready for 2.11.1\$
```

Note that a newline embedded within an `author` or `committer` line would end that line and start a new record, leaving a bad line in place.  In any case it would not come out as part of `%ce`.

Where that apparent-newline is coming from is a mystery to me.  Find the mystery character that acts like, yet cannot be, newline first, perhaps?  In any case note that `git commit` uses `$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` from the environment, if it's set, or any value from `git -c user.email=expr`, before it uses the configured `user.email` value.